# Ionic2 input file single still takes multiple files on ios

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

```
<input 
#uploadFile
type="file"
single 
ng2FileSelect 
[uploader]="uploader" />
```

I set the input to accept one single file only and it works on my mac. However, this input still takes multiple photos from my iPhone album. I want to restrict users to only select one photo, is there anything I'm missing?